# Cannot import or install pandas-profiling in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, pip, jupyter-notebook, pandas-profiling

I have technically already installed pandas-profiling using

`pip install pandas-profiling`

But when I try to import it, I get the following error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e1a23f2a6f04> in <module>()
  1 import numpy as np
  2 import pandas as pd
  3 import pandas_profiling

  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_profiling'
```

[First Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv1zm.png)

So I tried installing it in Jupyter Notebook and got the following error as well:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas-profiling

 Collecting pandas-profiling
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas-profiling 
 (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for pandas-profiling
```

[Second Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz0kv.png)

I am also unable to install it using conda for both as I am unable to establish a connection to conda.anaconda.org for some reason.

Comment: Are you launching the notebook from your env that contains the modules?

Comment: I'm launching the notebook from inside the Anaconda root env.

Comment: I think you don't have permission to install in root env, considering that you are a user. So you cannot use it from root env. You need to install it properly in the environment where you can write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments I was able to figure out the issue. I had to install jupyter notebook outside of the Anaconda root env and open it from the terminal.

```
pip3 install jupyter notebook
```

Once I did that it imported properly.

Comment: Can you please explain the steps to do this?

Answer (score 6):

To others who are looking to resolve this issue try these alternate steps :

1. Run `pip install pandas-profiling` command in a separate cell in the jupyter notebook.
2. After this just restart the kernal and run again. This should definitely work. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

From Anaconda Prompt:

> > conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. [Download the ZIP](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/)
2. Open Anaconda Prompt and go to the directory and extract the files to a folder

> cd
>   C:\Users\farah\Downloads\pandas-profiling-master\pandas-profiling-master

3. Then type python setup.py install
4. Now you can use:

> ```
> import pandas_profiling as pp
> df = pd.read_csv('1234.csv')
> pp.ProfileReport(df)
> ```

Reference: [Pandas profiling](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/)

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install pandas_profiling  # Run this from Jupytor notebook Ignore the warnings if any 
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport #restart the kernel if throws error
ProfileReport(df)
```

Note: This worked for me on Windows 10